# How to create a close source SDK for iOS with other framework dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks, xcframework

I have multiple projects that build into XCFramework. For example:

- FeatureA.xcframework
- FeatureB.xcframework
- FeatureC.xcframework

When I build MySDK, it produces a .xcframework with a "frameworks" folder in it. FeatureA, B and C are inside that folder. This means that the frameworks were embeded.

But, when I add MySDK into another project and try to build I get: no such module "FeatureA" OR Could not build "FeatureA" to Objc.

The only way that my test project builds is by adding each .xcframework dependency. I tried using the search paths, but no luck.

I also tried change the modulemap file, but the error describe above continues.

I want to build a SDK, MySDK.xcframework that contains **all depencency frameworks**. In this way I hope that someone who wants to use my library will only have to import MySDK.xcframework.

What I want is even possible for iOS?